# how to pass a list of files to python open() method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of around 100 files form which I wanted to read and match one word.
Here's the piece of code I wrote.

```
import re
y = 'C:\\prova.txt'
var1 = open(y, 'r')

for line in var1:
    if re.match('(.*)version(.*)', line):
        print line

var1.close()
```

every time I try to pass a tuple to y I get this error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found.
```

(I think that `open()` does not accept any tuple but only strings)

So I could I get it to work with a list of files?

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are quite correct that `open` doesn't accept a tuple and needs a string. So you have to iterate over the file names one by one:

```
import re

for path in paths:
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.match('(.*)version(.*)', line):
                print line
```

Here I use `paths` as the variable the hold the file names — it can be a tuple or a list or some other object that you can iterate over.

Comment: -1 You could have at least copied the OP's regex verbatim. This one doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnMachin: I did try to copy the original regexp. The problem was that the OP didn't format his code, so `(.*)version(.*)` looked like "(.*)version(.*)". Please see [the original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9153439/1) of the question. I look forward to you removing your downvote.

Comment: @JohnMachin:  Please remember that you can **edit** my answers instead of downvoting them for trivial problems like this. Stack Overflow is meant to be a site where we improve the questions and answers — not a site where we nitpick on each other.

Comment: @MartinGeisler: It's worse than I thought: you blindly copied a NON-working regex. That's not a nitpick.

Comment: @John: `(.)version(.)` is not "NON-working". It matches "version" and captures the letter on each side. I'm sure you know that since you've answered tons of regex questions. You probably also noted that the question *isn't about the regex*. It's about opening files in a list.

Comment: @Martin: You mean "captures the any-character-but-newline on each side". "NON-working" == that regex used with `re.match()` doesn't do what the OP was intending: `re.search("version", line)` or `version in line`

Comment: @JohnMachin: as I've explained you, the original regex looked like `(.)version(.)`. That is a working regex and so I complain when you say it's "NON-working". That's all. I've fixed the answer now, so your down vote cannot apply any longer. Will you remove it?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`fileinput.input`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) instead of `open`.

> This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a loop over standard input **or a list of files**
>
> [...] To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file name is also allowed.

Example:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(list_of_files):
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over the tuple. And you don't need a regex here.

```
y = ('C:\\prova.txt', 'C:\\prova2.txt')
for filename in y:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'version' in line:
                print line
```

Using the `with` statement this way also saves you from having to close the files you're working with. They will be closed automatically when the `with` block is exited.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
import re

files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
for f in files:
  with open(f, 'r') as var1:
    for line in var1: 
      if re.match('(.*)version(.*)', line):
        print line
```

Comment: -1 You could have at least copied the OP's regex verbatim. This one doesn't work.

Comment: @John Actually, if you see the edits of the OP's question, this was the original at the time I started writing - updated now, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @nassio Sure thing, glad to help! I think Mark Byer's answer is the best for your situation, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def simple_search(filenames, query):
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                if query in line:
                    print filename, line_num, line.strip()
```

My added value: (1) it's useless printing the line contents without showing which line in which file (2) doesn't double-space the output